# How Do I put 2 matrix into scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I work with the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function.
My purpose is get `w,z` which minimize `f(w,z)`

Both `w` and `z` are *n* by *m* matrices:

```
[[1,1,1,1],
 [2,2,2,2]]
```

f(w,z) is receive parameter w and z.

I already tried the form given below:

```
def f(x):
   w = x[0]
   z = x[1]
   ...

minimize(f, [w,z])
```

but, minimize does not work well.

What is the valid form to put two matrices (*n* by *m*) into `scipy.optimize.minimize`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Optimize needs a 1D vector to optimize. You are on the right track. You need to flatten your argument to `minimize` and then in `f`, start with `x = np.reshape(x, (2, m, n))` then pull out `w` and `z` and you should be in business.

I've run into this issue before. For example, optimizing parts of vectors in multiple different classes at the same time. I typically wind up with a function that maps things to a 1D vector and then another function that pulls the data back out into the objects so I can evaluate the cost function. As in:

```
def toVector(w, z):
    assert w.shape == (2, 4)
    assert z.shape == (2, 4)
    return np.hstack([w.flatten(), z.flatten()])

def toWZ(vec):
    assert vec.shape == (2*2*4,)
    return vec[:2*4].reshape(2,4), vec[2*4:].reshape(2,4)

def doOptimization(f_of_w_z, w0, z0):
    def f(x): 
        w, z = toWZ(x)
        return f_of_w_z(w, z)

    result = minimize(f, toVec(w0, z0))
    # Different optimize functions return their
    # vector result differently. In this case it's result.x:
    result.x = toWZ(result.x) 
    return result
```

Comment: In case it is helpful for anyone, I created a simple package based on this answer to help generalize the creation and management of variables and constraints for use in larger projects with many variables. GitHub link here: https://github.com/andrewnyu/optimstruct